# Retrieving result attributes in Qiskit

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am trying to optimize a Hamiltonian using QAOA in IBM Qiskit.

I used the following 'minimize' function to get my result. (I am not including the whole code because it will get unnecessarily long).

```
   res = minimize(cost_func, x0, args=(ansatz, hamiltonian, estimator), method="COBYLA")
   res
```

When I ran the problem on a 'ibmq qasm simulator' I got the following result:

```
fun: -23.1424
   maxcv: 0.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 45
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([3.39824022, 4.17447906, 2.86297948, 3.1139919 ])
```

I got multiple attributes in the solution.

But when I ran this on an actual quantum computer (ibm brisbane), I used the same code and same variable 'res'; it went on Queue and I had to wait for around 4-5 hours. But after the job was done, I cannot get the value for res which was defined in the previous line of code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[1], line 1
    res
NameError: name 'res' is not defined
```

And I tried using job.result() but that doesn't have the required attributes I got from the results of the simulator stored in variable 'res'.

How can I get the attributes such as res.x from the already completed job?